# jquery screen size not reflect until refresh the page

Tags: jquery

hihi guys, the problem is when the screen is below 768px, the function of height(); is run, everything is fine, but when i drag the window screen to **more than 768px**, the ** height(); function is **still remain on there** (it should be disappear when above 768px) , but if i **refresh the page**, **the height(); function just will be disappear**.
may i know where is the problem?

```
modalPop : function() {
    (function($) {
        //
        'use strict';

        // modal
        var popups = $('.modal-boz'),
            totalPopups = popups.length;

        if ( popups.length ) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < totalPopups; i++ ) {
                var popup = $(popups[i]);

                popup.each(function() {

                    $(this).children('a.cta').click(function(e) {
                        $(this).parent().children('.popup-modal').fadeIn(350);
                        if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
                            var _topPos = $('body').height() - $('.popup-modal .form-wrapper').height();
                            _topPos-= 300;
                            $('.popup-modal > .modal-content').css('top',_topPos+'px');
                           console.log('top section show')
                        } else {
                           console.log('top section hidden')
                        }
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            }
        }

    })(jQuery);
}
```

Comment: You are checking for width not height in your code.

Comment: i am checking for width of window size if under <768, it run the function of this  var _topPos = $('body').height() - $('.popup-modal .form-wrapper').height();
topPos-= 300;
$('.popup-modal > .modal-content').css('top',_topPos+'px'); else if above 768px it will remove that function ,but problem is i need to refresh the page the script just will disappear

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach a function to the window resize event.

`$(window).on('resize', function (event) { ... })`

This will call the provided function every time the window changes width or height.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize